# How do I add a meta tag to my website so that in my iPhone web view, the pop up doesn't show when the person holds a link?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, meta-tags

Right now, on the iphone, when the person holds down the link, , it'll have a bottom drawer pop up and say, "Open", "Copy", "cancel".

I want to add a meta tag to disable this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you even want to do this? It smells similar to "I want to disallow people from downloading my images" which has a few almost-there tricks but is pretty much ultimately impossible. I suspect you're going to find out the same here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A meta tag will not disable them. But the following css will:

```
a {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

**EDIT**: The CSS will not disable the menu from popping up. It will only disable the magnifying glass. The only way I know of that disables the menu is to use onClick instead of href. Something like

```
<a onclick="window.location.href='somepage.html'">Link</a>
```

Comment: I have that, but when I hold down a link, it still happens. "Open", and "copy".

Comment: That disables the magnifying glass and copy stuff though.